# Aligning objects in camera view

Tags: camera, light, navigation

Several things are off and I don't know how to fix them.

1. How do I get all my objects and grid lines into camera focus? If I have a camera somewhere, I certainly don't know where it is.
2. How do I place the donut onto the plane. Right now, it passes through the plane like a ghost. [image]

Comment: It would appear that you are currently looking through your camera, so I'm not sure what you mean when you say you don't know where the camera is. For positioning the donut, have you tried clicking on the menu with the orange square, and manually setting the z position to zero? (or zero plus an offset based on the height of the donut)

Comment: Where's the menu with the orange square?

Comment: thats the Object Properties menu in the outliner panel on the right